# Sum of all integers in an interval - Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method that returns the sum of all the numbers in an interval between two integers. If x is negative or y < x, the method should return -1. But I am stuck. Why do the results show 0 and not -1? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
public int sumRange(int x, int y){
int sum = 0;
for(int i = x ; i <= y ; i++){
    sum = sum + i;
    if((y < x)||(x < 0)){
        return -1;
    }
}
return sum;
```

}

[image]

Comment: Please do not post your code as a picture but include it as code-formatted text inside your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `x < 0 || y < x` to return `-1` even before the loop starts.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(sumRange(10, 20));
        System.out.println(sumRange(20, 10));
        System.out.println(sumRange(-5, 20));
    }

    public static int sumRange(int x, int y) {
        if (x < 0 || y < x) {
            return -1;
        }
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = x; i <= y; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
165
-1
-1
```

Alternatively, you can use the mathematical formula to calculate the value.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sumRange(10, 20));
        System.out.println(sumRange(20, 10));
        System.out.println(sumRange(-5, 20));
    }

    public static int sumRange(int x, int y) {
        if (x < 0 || y < x) {
            return -1;
        }
        return y * (y + 1) / 2 - x * (x - 1) / 2;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
165
-1
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass x parameter smaller than y, it won't even enter the for loop, because it doesn't meet conditions. Like this case:

```
public class Main
    {
        public static int sumRange(int x, int y){
            int sum = 0;
            for(int i = x ; i <= y ; i++){
                sum = sum + i;
                if((y < x)||(x < 0)){
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            return sum;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int sum = sumRange(6,5);
            System.out.print(sum);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

answer from @Arvind Kumar Avinash is works well,i just add a method use Stream API to calculate sum of numbers.

```java
private int sumIntRange(int x, int y) {
    if (x < 0 || x > y) {
        return -1;
    }
    return IntStream.range(x, y + 1).sum();
}
```

Test cases:

```java
@Test
public void test_sumIntRange() {
    // test for boundary condition
    Assert.assertEquals(-1, sumIntRange(-1, 10));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1, sumIntRange(1, 0));
    Assert.assertEquals(10, sumIntRange(10, 10));
    Assert.assertEquals(165, sumIntRange(10, 20));

}
```